# In which cases does JpaRepository automatically create the query without you having to use @Query annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am following a Udemy tutorial in Spring boot. There's a part where `@Query` wasn't used for a user-created method in the repository interface. It works, but I want to understand **when** JpaRepository takes care of the creation of query. In the **User** class below, `@Table` wasn't used.

`findByEmail(String email)` method works without any implementation/definition. So, my impression was that, JpaRepository automatically created the `Select from User where email = emailargument`

So here's what I have

A database named `reservation` with table `User`

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reservation
spring.datasource.username=root
```

**User.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class User extends AbstractEntity{

    
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.project.flightreservation.entities.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

User findByEmail(String email);

}
```

Comment: Query creation from method names: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When Spring Data creates a new Repository implementation, it analyses all the methods defined by the interfaces and tries to automatically generate queries from the method names. While this has some limitations, it's a very powerful and elegant way of defining new custom access methods with very little effort. [Ref](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

by implementing one of the Repository interfaces, the DAO will already have some basic CRUD methods (and queries) defined and implemented.

You can create more complex queries with this approach [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)
The one which you posted in question is called automatic custom query.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

JPA has ability to construct query in different ways. You can use queries derived from methodName with the predicates `IsStartingWith`, `StartingWith`, `StartsWith`, `IsEndingWith`, `EndingWith`, `EndsWith`, `IsNotContaining`, `NotContaining`, `NotContains`, `IsContaining`, `Containing`, `Contains` the respective arguments for these queries will get sanitized.

If you face the situation in which either the method name parser does not support the keyword you want to use or the method name would get unnecessarily ugly, you can use `@Query` for `namedQuery` support of `JPQL` or `nativeQuery`.

I would strongly suggest you to go through this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods)